# I want to enable the chapter after 24 hours of the update_at column in Laravel using carbon

Tags: laravel, date, php-carbon

I am making chapters, so I have to make the chapters in such a way that it enables after every 24 hours of the updated_at column

I have tried using carbon. It compares the current date with the updated_at column and takes the max value of coin as 5.

I have tried this logic but it didnt worked for me

```
@if (! \Carbon\Carbon::now()->between(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($updated_at[0]), \Carbon\Carbon::parse($updated_at[0])->addHours(24)) && coins[0] == 5)
                <a href="{{route('gratitude_worksheet_home')}}" class="disabled">
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        EdQuest
                        <div class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"><img src="{{asset('imgs/coins.svg')}}" alt="Coin icon" style="width:35px;"> {{$coins[1]}} out of 13</div>
                    </li>
                </a>
                @else
                <a href="{{route('gratitude_worksheet_home')}}" >
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            EdQuest
                            <div class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"><img src="{{asset('imgs/coins.svg')}}" alt="Coin icon" style="width:35px;"> {{$coins[1]}} out of 13</div>
                        </li>
                </a>
@endif
```

My Css

```
<style>
a.disabled {
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($updated_at[0])->addHours(24) < \Carbon\Carbon::now() && coins[0] == 5 )
```

condition above are to check coins = 5 , and updated_at + 24 hours less than current time stamp

but you should do backend validation in your route here `gratitude_worksheet_home` in case someone trying to direct access

Comment: I'll be putting a middleware... and It wont be direclty accessible it will have an unlock key

Comment: Can you make it syntactically correct? ... It has some syntax error in the angular brackets

Comment: i can't , not enough provided data for coins, and updated_at structure, i just played around your question, you can just adjust with your current code, you don't need between, just add updated_at->addDay(1) or ->addHours(24) the math operator to current timestamp thats all

Comment: No the comparison operator is breaking the condition and on the browser it is showing like  < \Carbon\Carbon::now() && coins[0] == 5 )

Comment: What if i Want now time in UTC?

Comment: you can adjust the rest with carbon documentation https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Just do this simple like this below:

```
@if($chapter->updated_at->greaterThan(now()->addHours(24))){
   //DO YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: That's not what I have to do

Comment: your logic will be like started again as soon as the browser refreshes and I dont want that.. What i want is as soon as my coin value becomes 5 then from that updated_at I have to disable the href for 24 hrs only

Comment: Your question is not clear, you don't want refresh browser ? If that, you should use AJAX

Comment: Can you provide me with solution to ajax?

Comment: Please detail your question more, `AJAX` or even `realtime` will be solution for that case.

Comment: See what i have to do is I store timestamp in database, so as soon as the coins becomes 5 the timestamp is updated. So I have to check the coin value should be 5 and from that timestamp I have to disable the href link for 24 hours and then enable it.. Am I clear now?